# need function(s) to match name to comma-delimited list

Tags: r, substring, match

I have a list of SNP names of length 2139. 
I have been trying to match each one of these names one a time to this   character list of 23 rows, where each row contains multiple names so
that I can assign the locus name for each SNP.

I have tried `grep` and match and nothing is working. This shows the first 10 elements of my character vector that has the SNP names:

```
   [1] kgp32557    kgp37275    kgp38994    kgp45973    kgp53783      kgp61605    kgp73110    kgp74757
```

And this shows the character list of 23 rows (truncated as well
because many names in each row so I show a list of names in row 1):

```
    [1,]   kgp9852430,rs1017860,rs7242868,kgp7009716,kgp6611434,kgp4808508,rs2850724,kgp3871878,kgp16151703,kgp16188651,rs9954562,kgp16153963,kgp7895020,....
```

Comment: Please use `dput()`, and you can try `require(tidyverse)

snpNames <- c("kgp32557", "kgp37275", "kgp38994", "kgp45973", "kgp53783", "kgp61605")

snpMatch <- c("kgp32557", "kgp2345", "kgp2346", "kgp45973", "kgp53783", "kgp61605")

snpMatch[snpNames %in% snpMatch]`

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). The link I provided, will tell you how. Moreover, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers.

Comment: Thank you...I will try this!

Comment: This is not working, I have wihsnoquote, a vector of 2136 names where I need to match each name to the row that has its name in genelocusnoquote which has 23 rows and 1 column. Each row of this matrix has a comma-delimited row where I gave an example of one row as shown above. This works going one one name and one row at a time but not in a loop:  grep(wihsnamenoquote[1],genelocusnoquote[3,1])
Please help, thank you.